# How Can I Sort JTable With A Button?

Tags: java

Example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN27C.jpg]

I made a table, and I want a search box for each column. I hid the column titles with this code:

```
table.setTableHeader(null);
```

And put a textField and Button to each top of columns. Now I can search for each different column, but I can't sort the items.

I want to sort the column items when I click the top button. I tried some thing but it is so complex for a beginner as me.

Is there any way to do it? Or all the thing i tried useless and there is much easy way to do it? I hope explained it right.

Note :
I have found this code.I dont even know if it does what i need. I did try it but getting error.

```
/** Default sort behaviour, plus every third click removes the sort. */
  private final class CustomSorter extends MouseAdapter {
    @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent aEvent) {
      int columnIdx = fTable.getColumnModel().getColumnIndexAtX(aEvent.getX());
      //build a list of sort keys for this column, and pass it to the sorter
      //you can build the list to fit your needs here 
      //for example, you can sort on multiple columns, not just one
      List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<>();
      //cycle through all orders; sort is removed every 3rd click
      SortOrder order =  SortOrder.values()[fCountClicks % 3];
      sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(columnIdx, order));
      fSorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
      ++fCountClicks;
    }
    private int fCountClicks;
  }
}
```

And did try this and getting same error.

```
btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                table.getRowSorter().toggleSortOrder(1);
            }
        });
```

Error:Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

This is the code: [Code](https://pastebin.com/VVv24FiP)

This is the what program looks like : [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuXMU.jpg)

Comment: You're probably better off to use the JTable as it's supposed to be used with column headers.  Create a table search combining a JComboBox with the column names, a JTextField, and a search JButton.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc That's what I was going to say

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc You probably right but i like this idea and i am so close to finish it. I will try my best to do it. Iam just trying to learn so if i can't finish it , i will do what you said. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: 1) The code should be posted in the forum. 2) An [mre] should be posted. We are NOT interested in your application. Your question is about sorting a column in a table. So all you need is a JFrame, with a JTable and the buttons to sort the column. So then entire code should be about 20-30 lines of code. The point of the "MRE" is to simplify the problem. Then once you get it working in  simple example you fix your real application now that you understand the concept.

Comment: @camickr the code updated [Code](https://pastebin.com/VVv24FiP)

Comment: @Gresta, 1) code should be posted in the forum. 2) Class names should start with an upper case character. Learn Java conventions and follow them if you want help from people in the forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `ActionListener` of your `JButton` you can try sorting the column with code like:

```
table.getRowSorter().toggleSortOrder(columnIndex);
```

This should allow you to click the button to reverse the sort order each time it is clicked.

Edit:

As I said in my comment you need to learn how to solve a NullPointerException.

The stack trace when I run the code states:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at frame1$2.actionPerformed(frame1.java:83)
```

Line 83 is:

```
table.getRowSorter().toggleSortOrder(0);
```

So you have two variables at that statement:

1. table
2. table.getRowSorter()

It is up to you to determine which variable is null

So you add debug code before that statement:

```
System.out.println( table );
System.out.println( table.getRowSorter() );
```

If you do you will see that `table.getRowSorter()` returns null.

So now you can ask a proper question like:

**"Why does table.getRowSorter() return null?"**

The answer is simple you didn't set the properties of the table to do sorting.

This is easily done by adding:

```
table.setModel(model);
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true); // added
```

In the future do some basic debugging BEFORE asking a question. You can't code if you don't know the basics of debugging code.

My original answered assumed you new how to sort columns in a table when using the table header and you just wanted to know how to use a separate button. That is why a "MRE" should be posted with EVERY question so we don't have to guess what your code is really doing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tryed that but getting an error like this and i dont understand why : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: full stack trace needed. and maybe code.. -> https://pastebin.com/

Comment: [Code](https://pastebin.com/n4sram2U) This is the code. [Picture](https://imgur.com/a/CLnLduy) And this is how the program looks like. I can share more if  you need.

Comment: Well, solve the NullPointerException. The stack trace tells you the statement causing the problem. So figure out which variable is null and then fix the problem. In the code I suggested you are only referencing the "table" variable, so is likely null. That probably means you define the variable twice, once as an instance variable (which is null) and once as a local variable. Get rid of the local variable.

Comment: @camickr Thanks for answering. But the thing is my code works fine until i try what you said. When i write a code for mause event ,i get the error. This is what i wrote as event.[Code](https://pastebin.com/VmHrCW7t)."toggleSortOrder()" says "IndexOutOfBoundsException - if column is outside the range ofthe underlying model". but i dont know what is the problem.

Comment: First you have a NullPointerException, now you have a IndexOutOfBounds. I don't know what is causing your confusion. Java indexes are 0 based. So you use 0 for the first column. If you still get the exception then you are using the wrong index. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @camickr Well first of all realy thanks for answering all of my questions.I am new here and trying to learn how the system works. Sory if i explained my problem wrong. But there is nothing to share more abouth the code. I simply use a mause click listener with the code you gave me(update the code in post). And when i click the button i get (java.lang.NullPointerException) this error. I dont get the secont error. I saw it when i try  to write that code you gave me and the box on the right hade article abouth (if column is outside the range ofthe underlying model)(IndexOutOfBoundsException).

Comment: @camickr well thats fixed everthing. Sory for taking your time for days :) . As you can see i am new at this and it is not my first language. Thanks for all of your help.