# How can I open a frame and close the old one with a button?

Tags: java

I have 2 frames. `Frame1` list a table with data. `Frame2` puts new data to table. And a button opens `Frame2`. In `Frame2`, I write the things to put the table and write them to a txt file. And in `Frame1`, I put items from a txt file to the table.

However, when I go back to the `Frame1`, it is still the old table. Because I have not reset it. Because it gets items when it opens and it opens before `Frame2`. So I want to close `Frame1` when I click the button and open `Frame2`. And after I am done with `Frame2`, I want to go back to `Frame1`. So `Frame1` can be the new table.

Here is what I wrote but when I click the button `Frame1` does not close:

```
btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        
        try {
            Frm1 frm1 = new Frm1();//using try / catch becouse of files.
            Frm2 frm2 = new Frm2();
            frm1.setVisible(false);// i made it as frm2 first and frm1 after and nothing changed.
            frm2.setVisible(true);
            
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
    }
});
```

Note:

```
Frm1 frm1 = new Frm1();
```

I tried to take this code out of the event. But I get error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
```

I guess it is because of I already have it in (`public static void main(String[] args)`).

```
frm1.dispose();
```

And tried this too. Is it not working.

[Frame1 Code](https://pastebin.com/Q237cBA8)
[Frame2 Code](https://pastebin.com/SwaTQiZW)
[Fonks Code](https://pastebin.com/r3GEhwPt)

Comment: 1) Don't use a MouseListener. Instead you add an ActionListener to the button 2) Don't create multiple frames. An application should only have a single frame. So your frame will hold the JTable with the data. Then you create a child modal JDialog. So both the dialog and frame will be visible at the same time. Then when you close the dialog you do your processing on the frame. 3) You got help in your last question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/63364682/131872) and still haven't "accepted" the answer and you still haven't posted an [mre]. Every question should have an "MRE".

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an Frm1 and Frm2 object each time you click that button. So you are basicly not hiding your original Frm instead you hide the new one.
A simple idea to fix this issue would be to initialize both frames in an upper laying class like an controller class and just to set the visibilty of the Frm2 object to false. In the mouseClicked you can just swap the booleans from both frames then by using a global variable of them.

If my answer doesn't help please provide more code.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Now i understand whats is wrong. But now when i write ( Frm1 frm1 = new Frm1(); ) outside of the event and then start the program ,iget  error.(Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0") and after that i get tons of (at Frm1.<init>(Frm1.java:48))

Comment: So i just saw i already creat frm1 in (public static void main(String[] args)).I guess thats the problem. But i cant call it with (frm1.setVisible();) or (frm1.dispose();).

Comment: @Gresta can you post more code? Would help to see the all classes / methods that are interacting with your Frame stuff :)

Comment: i update the post with more code. Hope explained everything you need.